# How to play a video in flutter in landscape view?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a  video in my assets folder, and when I am trying the code, it is giving some exceptions. Can anyone help me?

```
class VideoExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  VideoState createState() => VideoState();
}
class VideoState extends State<VideoExample> {
  VideoPlayerController playerController;
  VoidCallback listener;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listener = () {
      setState(() {});
    };
  }

  void createVideo() {
    if (playerController == null) {
      playerController = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/videos/video.mp4")
      ..addListener(listener)
      ..setVolume(1.0)
      ..initialize();
    }
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    playerController.setVolume(0.0);
    playerController.removeListener(listener);
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Video'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              child: Container(
                child: (playerController != null
                    ? VideoPlayer(
                  playerController,
                )
                    : Container()),
              ))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          createVideo();
          playerController.play();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

I just want that the video should run in the full screen with landscape mode.

I had imported every essential package and changed the pubspec.yaml file.

It is playing the video but not playing it in full-screen landscape mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/chewie and https://pub.dev/packages/auto_orientation 
You can enter full screen mode with `_chewieController.enterFullScreen()`

code snippet

```
_chewieController = ChewieController(
    videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
    aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
    autoPlay: true,
    looping: true,
    routePageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondAnimation, provider) {
      return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animation,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return VideoScaffold(
            child: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
              body: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.black,
                child: provider,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }

FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _chewieController.enterFullScreen();
              },
              child: Text('Fullscreen'),
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:auto_orientation/auto_orientation.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:chewie/src/chewie_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChewieDemo(),
  );
}

class ChewieDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  ChewieDemo({this.title = 'Chewie Demo'});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ChewieDemoState();
  }
}

class _ChewieDemoState extends State<ChewieDemo> {
  TargetPlatform _platform;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController2;
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');
    _videoPlayerController2 = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_20mb.mp4');
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
        aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: true,
        routePageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondAnimation, provider) {
          return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return VideoScaffold(
                child: Scaffold(
                  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
                  body: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: provider,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      // Try playing around with some of these other options:

      // showControls: false,
      // materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
      //   playedColor: Colors.red,
      //   handleColor: Colors.blue,
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      //   bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      // ),
      // placeholder: Container(
      //   color: Colors.grey,
      // ),
      // autoInitialize: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController1.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController2.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: widget.title,
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        platform: _platform ?? Theme.of(context).platform,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _chewieController.enterFullScreen();
              },
              child: Text('Fullscreen'),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _chewieController.dispose();
                        _videoPlayerController2.pause();
                        _videoPlayerController2.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                        _chewieController = ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
                          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          looping: true,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Video 1"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _chewieController.dispose();
                        _videoPlayerController1.pause();
                        _videoPlayerController1.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 0));
                        _chewieController = ChewieController(
                          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController2,
                          aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          looping: true,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Text("Video 2"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _platform = TargetPlatform.android;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Android controls"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _platform = TargetPlatform.iOS;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Text("iOS controls"),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VideoScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoScaffold({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _VideoScaffoldState();
}

class _VideoScaffoldState extends State<VideoScaffold> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    AutoOrientation.portraitAutoMode();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```